# Checking installed packages

Tags: packages, texlive, installing

I am running latexlive, I think everything is installed.  How can I check to see if the `etoolbox` and `ifthen` packages are installed?  I think these packages will solve my problems.

If they are not installed, what is the best way to install them on a Debian environment?

Comment: We meet again :) If you use the terminal heavily, you can use `kpsewhich etoolbox.sty` and check the exit code. But don't use `ifthen` – it's exceptionally out-of-date. Depending on your needs, there are a variety of better tools out there. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In your shell, try `tlmgr info etoolbox` or `tlmgr info --list etoolbox`.

Comment: @SeanAllred: In what way is `ifthen` "exceptionally out-of-date"?

Comment: There are much more modern/robust alternatives if you're doing programming in TeX -- expl3 is the one that comes to my mind. LuaTeX is also an option. `ifthen` was out-of-date 7(!) years ago -- it's very out-of-date now. That doesn't mean it won't work -- it just means it's probably not actively maintained/improved (unless something's changed in the years since I wrote that comment).

Answer (score 40):

The quickest way to check if a package is installed is to search for it with `kpsewhich {package-name}.sty`.  So, to check for `etoolbox`, use

```sh
$ kpsewhich etoolbox.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
```

If it finds the package, it will output the path (just like normal `which`).  If it doesn't find the package, it will output nothing and have a non-zero exit code.

---

Perhaps the most direct way to answer the question though would be to try and use the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The above will fail if `etoolbox` cannot be found.

Comment: Sorry you are right, texlive.  Let me check for etoolbox.sty and see.

Comment: As you said, this question is in the wring area.  Etoolbox is installed, but the .tex file crashes if I include \usepackage{etoolbox}.....  where should I post this ?

Comment: @GregoryWest I can vouch that this answer is correct, so perhaps you should ask your *actual* question in a new post with a MWE. See also [What is the X–Y problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188148).

Answer (score 3):

Using the bash command `locate` in Unix find the `texlive` directory in your system:

```
$ locate texlive
```

Mine is in `/usr/local/texlive`. Once located you can see all the packages installed in your latex library using `ls`. In my case:

```
$ ls /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*/*.sty
```

Gives me the complete set of packages (`sty` files) available in my computer with texlive.

Edit: Another purer latex way would be to compile one `tex` file, call it `myfile.tex` (with a line `\usepackage{my-package}`) and open `myfile.log` to see where is `pdflatex` loading the package from. In your case finding the `texlive` path.

Answer (score 2):

Even though, a good answer has been given to the first question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248306/117801) for example, it seems nobody actually dealt with the second one for Debian installation of the LaTeX packages.

A quite easy way is to use `apt-file` to search in which Debian package the LaTeX package is included :

```
apt-file search yourPackage.sty
```

This will display at the beginning of line the Debian package to install then, with classic `sudo apt install ...` command.